# polymorphic deserialization of JSON with jackson, property type becomes "null"

Tags: java, android, jackson

I am using Jackson to convert a big Json string into various classes and subclasses.

I have a list of objects, each containing a node object, a last result object and a children array. The children array contains a list of objects with exactly the same setup. This goes on for 3 or 4 layers.

Each layers' node is of a different subclass, which all extend from a node superclass. 
I have annotated the superclass node with following annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type1ResponseDto.class, name = "Type1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type2ResponseDto.class, name = "Type2"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type3ResponseDto.class, name = "Type3"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type4ResponseDto.class, name = "Type4"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type5ResponseDto.class, name = "Type5")
})
```

This seems to work, since all subclasses get mapped.

However, this somehow results in the "type" property being set to null.

Any ideas as to why this happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jackson - @JsonTypeInfo property is being mapped as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611199/jackson-jsontypeinfo-property-is-being-mapped-as-null)

Answer (score 11):

I needed to add `visible=true` for the type property to show up:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "type",visible = true)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type1ResponseDto.class,name =  "Type1"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type2ResponseDto.class, name = "Type2"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type3ResponseDto.class, name = "Type3"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type4ResponseDto.class, name = "Type4")
})
```

Comment: Which version of Jackson does this answer apply to?  I'm using 1.9.9 and I don't have those options, and I'm having this exact issue.