# Jackson - @JsonTypeInfo property is being mapped as null?

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization

Say I have the following JSON:

```
{  
    "id":"decaa828741611e58bcffeff819cdc9f",
    "statement":"question statement",
    "exercise_type":"QUESTION"
}
```

then, based on the `exercise_type` field, I want to instantiate different objects instances (subclasses of `ExerciseResponseDTO`). In order to do that, I tried creating this mix in:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "exercise_type")  
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = ExerciseChoiceResponseDTO.class, name = "CHOICE"),  
    @Type(value = ExerciseQuestionResponseDTO.class, name = "QUESTION")})  
public abstract class ExerciseMixIn  
{}  

public abstract class ExerciseResponseDTO {

    private String id;
    private String statement;
    @JsonProperty(value = "exercise_type") private String exerciseType;
    
    // Getters and setters 
}

public class ExerciseQuestionResponseDTO
    extends ExerciseResponseDTO {}

public class ExerciseChoiceResponseDTO
    extends ExerciseResponseDTO {}
```

and then the mapper `ObjectMapper` as follows

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.addMixIn(ExerciseResponseDTO.class, ExerciseMixIn.class);
```

but for some reason, this test fails:

```
ExerciseResponseDTO exercise = mapper.readValue(serviceResponse, ExerciseResponseDTO.class)
Assert.assertTrue(exercise.getClass() == ExerciseQuestionResponseDTO.class);    // OK
Assert.assertEquals("decaa828741611e58bcffeff819cdc9f" exercise.getId());       // OK
Assert.assertEquals("question statement", exercise.getStatement());             // OK
Assert.assertEquals("QUESTION", exercise.getExerciseType());                    // FAIL. Expected: "QUESTION", actual: null
```

seems like there's an issue specifically with the `exercise_type` attribute that's not being mapped for some reason, since all the other fields are being mapped just fine. Any idea what could it be causing this?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Finally, I've found the solution in the [API Doc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html)

> Note on visibility of type identifier: by default, deserialization
> (use during reading of JSON) of type identifier is completely handled
> by Jackson, and is not passed to deserializers. However, if so
> desired, it is possible to define property visible = true in which
> case property will be passed as-is to deserializers (and set via
> setter or field) on deserialization.

So the solution was simply adding the '*visible*' attribute as follows

```
@JsonTypeInfo(  
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,  
    property = "exercise_type",
    visible = true)  
@JsonSubTypes({  
    @Type(value = ExerciseChoiceResponseDTO.class, name = "CHOICE"),  
    @Type(value = ExerciseQuestionResponseDTO.class, name = "QUESTION")})  
public abstract class ExerciseMixIn  
{}
```

Comment: I hope God will reward you and give you everything you need :)))) I searched a few hours for this.

Comment: not working, that's the default implementation generated by openapi-generator, but when serialized to json when calling my REST controller, my field is always "null".

Comment: cool. same for EXISTING_PROPERTY

Comment: debugged all the library to find it's the `visibile` property that causing it. Simple google search led me to here.

Answer (score 9):

As per [@jscherman answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611726/3189940) by setting, 'visible' true in JsonTypeInfo will help in accessing exercise_type as a field.

If you use the same class to serialize also then resulting JSON will have exercise_type appear twice. So it's better to also update include to [JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html#EXISTING_PROPERTY)

And it's also worth looking at [all other options](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.As.html) for include.