# Spring-Data-REST and a polymorphic member

Tags: java, json, spring, polymorphism, spring-data-rest

I have a class that I'm exposing via Spring Data REST, it looks like this, getters and setters, as well as irrelevant fields, are omitted:

```
public class System {
    @NotNull
    @Valid
    @OneToOne(optional = false, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "FLOW_ID")
    private FlowConfig flow;
}
```

FlowConfig itself isn't exposed via a RestRepository, it looks like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY, property = "@type")
//@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name = "FLOWCONFIG")
@Audited
public abstract class FlowConfig extends BaseEntity {
    // Some fields, none of them representing the type of the entity
}
```

The problem is that both `@JsonTypeInfo` annotations don't work, I never get type information in the JSON output. Whatever I put, I never get the `@type` in the resulting JSON.

According to [this link](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREST-900), `EXISTING_PROPERTY` should work, but it doesn't. If I test JSON output with a default `ObjectMapper`, both annotations produce what I want.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? 
I'm on version 2.6.9 of spring-data-rest-webmvc.

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33611726/5380322) can help...