# How to deserialize JSON via JsonTypeInfo with unknown property

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I need to deserialize JSON looks like the following:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "id": "id1",
    "type": "type1"
    "name": "John",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "id2",
    "type": "type2",
    "name": "Rebecca",
    ...
  },
  {
    "id": "id3",
    "type": "unknown",
    "name": "Peter",
    ...
  }]
}
```

For deserializing JSON which I have written above I have created a couple of classes:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type",
        defaultImpl = DefaultData.class
)
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type1Data.class, name = "type1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Type2Data.class, name = "type2")
})
public class AbstractData {
    public final String id;
    public final String type;
    public final String name;
    public AbstractData(String id, String type, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public class Type1Data extends AbstractData {
    @JsonCreator
    public Type1Data(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                     @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {
        super(id, "type1", name);
    }
}

public class DefaultData extends AbstractData {
    @JsonCreator
    public DefaultData(@JsonProperty("id") String id, 
                       @JsonProperty("type") String type,
                       @JsonProperty("name") String name
    ) {
        super(id, type, name);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        AbstractData data = mapper.readValue(json, AbstractData.class);
    }
}
```

I get an exception if I use default implementation:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'unknown' as a type
```

The class `DefaultData` I need to avoid a deserialization exception if I will get the unknown type.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Which version of Jackson is used?

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov I use ```2.10.2``` version.

Comment: try to add this to your AbstractData class

@JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DefaultData.class, name = "unknown")

Comment: Do you known why do we need @JsonCreator here? Looks like visible=true param should be automatically set it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Summary

Right now it is not clear what is the **exact** root cause of the problem, because your example works for me with several corrections.

Still, please, consider the corrections as a draft.

## Corrections

### Data class for root object: Introduced

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class RootData {
    public final AbstractData[] data;

    @JsonCreator
    public RootData(@JsonProperty("data") final AbstractData[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", RootData.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
            .add("data=" + Arrays.toString(data))
            .toString();
    }
}
```

### `AbstractData` data class: Updated to deserialize `type` property

Please, see [the Javadoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.10.1/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.html):

> Note on visibility of type identifier: by default, deserialization (use during reading of JSON) of type identifier is completely handled by Jackson, and is **not passed to** deserializers. However, if so desired, it is possible to define property `visible = true` in which case property will be passed as-is to deserializers (and set via setter or field) on deserialization.

Updated annotation by adding `visible = true`:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    property = "type",
    visible = true,
    defaultImpl = DefaultData.class
)
```

Additionally, please, see the related question: [java - Jackson - @JsonTypeInfo property is being mapped as null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611199/jackson-jsontypeinfo-property-is-being-mapped-as-null).

### Data classes: Implemented `toString()` method

(Omitted.)

### Main: Updated to use root data class

Please, note that I have corrected the JSON document: added the missing comma after `"type": "type1"`.

```java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final String jsonDocumentString =
            """
            {
              "data": [{
                "id": "id1",
                "type": "type1",
                "name": "John"
              },
              {
                "id": "id2",
                "type": "type2",
                "name": "Rebecca"
              },
              {
                "id": "id3",
                "type": "unknown",
                "name": "Peter"
              }]
            }
            """;

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final RootData rootData = mapper.readValue(jsonDocumentString, RootData.class);
        System.out.println(rootData);
    }
}
```

The program completes successfully, i.e. without an exception being thrown.
The program outputs:

```
RootData[data=[Type1Data[id='id1', type='type1', name='John'], Type2Data[id='id2', type='type2', name='Rebecca'], AbstractData[id='id3', type='unknown', name='Peter']]]
```

The actual result (output) is the same as the expected result.

Comment: But in your response ```AbstractData[id='id3', type='null', name='Peter']]``` the ```type``` property is null, but I want to get ```type``` equals ```unknown``` value.

Comment: @John, good catch! Sorry. Please, see the updated answer.

Comment: Wondering why do we need to specify "type1", "type2". Why can't it just take it from the json string?